# Open map effect in the Yahoo! Weather app for iOS

Tags: ios

how can I create the same effect of the app Yahoo! Weather on iOS, which verifcation when you touch the preview of this map and switch to fullscreen

Comment: What have you tried?  You will have more chance at getting help if you provide the code you have tried.

Comment: unfortunately I have not done any testing, because I have no idea how to recreate this effect

Comment: Then I suggest some research is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be like this:
(when you touch on map)

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f]; //set your value
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

mapView.center =mapView.center; //mapView is your map which subclass of UIView
mapView.bounds.origin.x=0;
mapView.bounds.origin.y=0
mapView.bounds.size.width=320; //set your value
mapView.bounds.size.height=460; //set your value

[mapView becomeFirstResponder];    

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

If its code will be work some incorrect, write it in comments.

Comment: Can you check my answer like correct (green mark). Your are welcome!

Comment: `beginAnimations` / `commitAnimations`? If you are going to give advice at least make it up to date. These two calls have been discouraged in favour of block based animations since iOS 4. And what is the point of  `mapView.center = mapView.center`?

Comment: Abizern, I understood you. I'm not professional like you, I'm beginner and my answers can be some incorrect. Thank you for advice! I'll be care about it.

Comment: @KirillProkopovich It's not a matter of being a beginner. Maybe you picked up this animation technique from some tutorial. But here's some advice; when you are using methods from a tutorial, don't just blindly follow them - have a look at the documentation for the method. In this case the begin/commitAnimation methods are clearly discouraged. Learning to use the documentation is part of learning to program. Using the modern API is also easier than using the older one.

Comment: Thank you again. I visited your site, its very interesting!